# Assiging the same value for another column

Tags: sas, datastep

I have a task in SAS;
What I need to do is to assign the October Current_value (60) in the column Fake_1 and let repeat it only for the months of October, November and December; the same logic should be applied to valorise column Fake_2, and assign the Current_Value of November both for November and December of columns Fake_2.
That's how my table should look like:

```
Product_Code    Division    Category    Payment_Frequency   Selling_Type    expiring_month  Current_Value   Fake_1  Fake2
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             1               63      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             2               72      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             3               23      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             4               24      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             5               90      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             6               87      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             7               56      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             8               43      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             9               57      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             10              60          60      
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             11              48          60      48
C611720         17822           AZ          Monthly             NSD             12              32          60      48
```

How can it be done? I think the solution would be using retain function, but I am struggling a bit as when I use it, sas prints me value of 48 and 32 for Nov/Dec values in the column fake1.

```
data sox_8;
set sox_7;
retain Fake_1;
if Expiring_Month > 9 then Fake_1 = Current_Value;
run;
```

Thank you for the support

Answer (score 1):

The `> 9` means it updates for 10, 11, and 12.  You want only to update on 10, so:

```
data sox_8;
  set sox_7;
  retain Fake_1;
  if Expiring_Month = 10 then Fake_1 = Current_Value;
run;
```

Now, you may want to extend your code like so:

```
data sox_8;
  set sox_7;
  array Fake[*] Fake_1-Fake_2;
  retain Fake_1-Fake_2;
  if Expiring_Month gt 9 and Expiring_Month lt 12 then 
    Fake[Expiring_Month-9] = Current_Value;
run;
```

This will update for both 10 and 11.  Presumably you'll eventually have code that, for 2021 perhaps, would need to do this for more than two months - this allows you the beginning of a program that will automatically pick up what it needs (you'll want to also calculate `Fake` dimensions based on the month you run, probably with a macro variable).

```
%let curmonth=10;
data sox_8;
  set sox_7;
  array Fake[*] Fake_1-Fake_%sysevalf(12-&curmonth);
  retain Fake_:;
  if Expiring_Month ge &curmonth and Expiring_Month lt 12 then 
    Fake[Expiring_Month - &curmonth + 1] = Current_Value;
run;
```

Of course, please don't use `Fake` as a variable name in your real code!